# How to remove a hole from a solid plane?

Tags: mesh, workflow

I have an object with a solid plane and multiple holes in the plane: [image: holes]

Now I want to remove only a single one of these holes. How to do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the faces around the holes that you dont want press x and then select the edge loop and press f for fill the place again.

Comment: An example including keys to press would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Using *Circle Select*, select all vertices of one side of hole (drag circle around hole).

Right click and merge vertices at center.
Repeat previous steps until only one vertex remains.
Right click and dissolve vertex.
Repeat process for other side of hole.

Results in clean planes.